# Mostrar espacios en php de una consulta en mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, Cuando hago una busqueda en la base de datos desde un formulario con PHP y
meto en el formulario "el  campeon" a pesar de que sí que existe
en la base de datos no me lo encuentra. esto me pasa solo cuando hay dos espacios, ya que con un solo espacio si me encuentra los datos correspondientes.

Comment: Debes agregar el código involucrado, el formulario y el **php** de búsqueda.

Comment: Cual es tu código? que haz hecho? cuales son tus errores? debes colocar lo que llevas, para que podamos ayudarte